# MergeSort Algorithm from largest to smallest in java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop, mergesort

So I want to use the mergesort algorithm to sort an array filled with numbers from largest to smallest. I have working code for this but I can't seem to make it sort from largest to smallest. I tried playing around with the for loop that has all of those if statements in there but I just couldn't figure it out. Could someone please help.

```
public class MergeSorter
{
    public void merge(int[] a, int l, int h) {
        if (h <= l) return;

        int result = (l + h) / 2;
        merge(a, l, result);
        merge(a, result + 1, h);
        sort_descend(a, l, result, h);
    }
    
    public void sort_descend(int[] a, int l, int result, int h) {
    
        int first_replace[] = new int[result - l + 1];
        int second_replace[] = new int[h - result];
        
        for (int i = 0; i < first_replace.length; i++)
            first_replace[i] = a[l + i];
        for (int i = 0; i < second_replace.length; i++)
            second_replace[i] = a[result+ i + 1];
        
        int first_i = 0;
        int second_i = 0;
            
        for (int i = l; i < h + 1; i++) {
            
            if (first_i < first_replace.length && second_i < second_replace.length) {
                if (first_replace[first_i] < second_replace[second_i]) {
                   a[i] = first_replace[first_i];
                   first_i++;
                } else {
                    a[i] = second_replace[second_i];
                    second_i++;
                }
            } else if (first_i < first_replace.length) {
                a[i] = first_replace[first_i];
                first_i++;
            } else if (second_i < second_replace.length) {
                a[i] = second_replace[second_i];
                second_i++;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

```
import java.util.Arrays; 
public class MergeSortTest
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = new int[]{ 6, 1, 3, 8, 3, 9, 2 };
        MergeSorter ms = new MergeSorter();
        ms.merge(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }  
}
```

Comment: A different choice of variable names would make this easier to follow. The function you're calling `merge` is normally called `mergesort`, and the function you're calling `sort_descend` is normally called `merge`. I'd also change `result` to something like `m` or `midpoint`.

Comment: I'd also suggest changing your indexing so that `h` is one past the end of the array (i.e., it's the size of the array). This is more conventional, so it's easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your entire logic is correct except one thing. In the `sort_descend` function, after you copy the array `a` into `first_replace` and `second_replace`, you start comparing the elements using the `if` condition `if (first_replace[first_i] < second_replace[second_i])`.

Here, you essentially assign the smaller of the two elements into your array `a` and this the step which determines whether your array will be sorted in ascending order or descending order.

To sort in descending order, you need to just reverse this sign and you will get the desired output i.e. change the if condition to `if (first_replace[first_i] > second_replace[second_i])`.

Comment: Worked like a charm, provided an answer with a WELL thought out explanation. Thank you !!!

Comment: @ozmrur Entirely my pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the below code to sort an array of integers in descending order.
It is similar to your solution but only one change of the comparator operator on line number 38.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class C
{
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] array = new int[]{ 6, 1, 3, 8, 3, 9, 2 };
        MergeSorter ms = new MergeSorter();
        ms.merge(array, 0, array.length - 1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
    }
}

class MergeSorter {
    public void merge(int[] a, int l, int h) {
        if (h <= l) return;

        int result = (l + h) / 2;
        merge(a, l, result);
        merge(a, result + 1, h);
        sort_descend(a, l, result, h);
    }

    public void sort_descend(int[] a, int l, int result, int h) {

        int first_replace[] = new int[result - l + 1];
        int second_replace[] = new int[h - result];

        for (int i = 0; i < first_replace.length; i++)
            first_replace[i] = a[l + i];
        for (int i = 0; i < second_replace.length; i++)
            second_replace[i] = a[result + i + 1];

        int first_i = 0;
        int second_i = 0;

        for (int i = l; i < h + 1; i++) {

            if (first_i < first_replace.length && second_i < second_replace.length) {
                if (first_replace[first_i] >= second_replace[second_i]) {
                    a[i] = first_replace[first_i];
                    first_i++;
                } else {
                    a[i] = second_replace[second_i];
                    second_i++;
                }
            } else if (first_i < first_replace.length) {
                a[i] = first_replace[first_i];
                first_i++;
            } else if (second_i < second_replace.length) {
                a[i] = second_replace[second_i];
                second_i++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```